# How do I remove all links from all my posts at once?

Tags: posts, links

I found this code but I don't understand it.

```php
add_filter( 'the_content', 'misha_remove_all_a' );
function misha_remove_all_a( $content ){
    return preg_replace('#<a.*?>(.*?)</a>#is', '\1', $content);
}
```

This is the  [link](https://refpasrasw.world/L?tag=d_273243m_7669c_&site=273243&ad=7669)

My website address is [this](https://fortybet.com)

Comment: Could you be a little more specific about your question? Not understanding it doesn't tell us what part isn't making sense. Do you need help figuring out where this goes? Or are you concerned about what it does?

Comment: What I mean is where do I place the link (I want to remove from all my posts) in that code.

Answer (score 0):

This code is a filter, as shown by the initial `add_filter` call. This type of code can either be placed in a custom plugin, or a child theme or custom theme's `functions.php` file. (You don't want to place it in an existing `functions.php` file because whenever you update the theme, it will get lost.)

It will automatically run on the front-end (public) view of every post, page, and custom post type. That's because the filter is added to `the_content`, which takes the content from the database and renders it out as HTML on the front end.

If you'd like to make this a plugin, you just need an opening PHP tag and a comment to let WordPress recognize it as a plugin:

```
<?php
/* Plugin Name: Strip Links from Content */
add_filter( 'the_content', 'misha_remove_all_a' );
function misha_remove_all_a( $content ){
    return preg_replace('#<a.*?>(.*?)</a>#is', '\1', $content);
}
?>
```

Save it as `strip-links.php`, upload it to `/wp-content/plugins/strip-links/`, and you can then activate the plugin from wp-admin.